# removing sub directory from url, in socialengine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, socialengine

I have linux based server, my host is site.x64.me and I have installed socialengine in /www/social450 and in domain it shows like this site.x64.me/social450  I want to remove social450 sub directory name from URL please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^social450/ /social450%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```